xcrysden opening errors
I recently installed edubuntu 24.04.l on my HP Pavilion laptop and I was planning to install and use xcrysden, but after a successful installation via the terminal by sudo apt-get install, I encountered the following error:
 Running on platform : unix
   Operating system : Linux
Package ImageMagick's convert: /usr/bin/convert
Package ImageMagick's import: /usr/bin/import
Package Ppmtompeg: /usr/bin/ppmtompeg
Package Xwd: /usr/bin/xwd
Executing: /usr/lib/xcrysden/ftnunit
Error in startup script: 
Couldn't configure togl widget
    while executing
"togl .mesa  -width          400  -height         400  -ident          .mesa  -rgba           $toglOpt(rgba)           -redsize        $toglOpt(redsize..."
    (procedure "PlaceGlobWin" line 107)
    invoked from within
"PlaceGlobWin 0 [expr round(670 * $fac1)] [expr round(670 * $fac1)]"
    (procedure "ViewMol" line 25)
    invoked from within
"ViewMol ."
    invoked from within
"if { [llength $argv] > 2 } {
    parseComLinArg [lrange $argv 2 end]
} else {
    ViewMol .
}"
    (file "/usr/share/xcrysden/Tcl/xcInit.tcl" line 633)``` 


 kernel information by ```uname -a```
``` Linux 6.8.0-51-generic #52-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC  x86_64 GNU/Linux'''


and for``` lspci -k```


```00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U 2p+8e cores Host Bridge/DRAM Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P/U 2p+8e cores Host Bridge/DRAM Controller
    Kernel driver in use: igen6_edac
    Kernel modules: igen6_edac
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics] (rev 04)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P [Iris Xe Graphics]
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915, xe
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake Dynamic Platform and Thermal Framework Processor Participant
    Kernel driver in use: proc_thermal_pci
    Kernel modules: processor_thermal_device_pci
00:06.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake PCIe 4.0 Graphics Port
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation GNA Scoring Accelerator module (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company GNA Scoring Accelerator module
00:0a.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake Crashlog and Telemetry
    Kernel driver in use: intel_vsec
    Kernel modules: intel_vsec
00:0d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P Thunderbolt 4 USB Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:12.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Integrated Sensor Hub (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P Integrated Sensor Hub
    Kernel driver in use: intel_ish_ipc
    Kernel modules: intel_ish_ipc
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH USB 3.2 xHCI Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
    Kernel modules: xhci_pci
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi (rev 01)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake PCH CNVi WiFi
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:15.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH HECI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: mei_me
    Kernel modules: mei_me
00:19.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:19.1 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P Serial IO I2C Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH PCIe Root Port #4 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P PCH PCIe Root Port
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1e.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH UART #0 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH UART
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1e.3 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake SPI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake SPI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-lpss
    Kernel modules: intel_lpss_pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake LPC/eSPI Controller
00:1f.3 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Raptor Lake-P/U/H cAVS
    Kernel driver in use: sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl
    Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel, snd_sof_pci_intel_tgl
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake PCH-P SMBus Host Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i801_smbus
    Kernel modules: i2c_i801
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Alder Lake-P PCH SPI Controller
    Kernel driver in use: intel-spi
    Kernel modules: spi_intel_pci
01:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013-E13 PCIe3 NVMe Controller (DRAM-less) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Phison Electronics Corporation PS5013-E13 PCIe3 NVMe Controller (DRAM-less)
    Kernel driver in use: nvme
    Kernel modules: nvme
02:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5228 (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device 8bf6
    Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
    Kernel modules: rtsx_pci``` 

When I tried Ubuntu 20.04 the xcrysden package was easily installed and started, but for some reason this problem has arisen in Ubuntu 24.04 Can anyone guide me to solve it?


Check the driver of the graphics card. Some problems are solved by installing the proper divers especially for the NDIVIA graphics card.

Check if your kernel version is compatible with the xcrysden requirement.

Uncomment the line WaylandEnable=false by sudo nano /etc/gdm3/custom.conf and restart the system using sudo systemctl restart gdm3



Tank you physics server2. i solve my problem according to xcrysden mailing archived.
http://www.democritos.it/pipermail/xcrysden/2024-July/002125.html
cd
mkdir .xcrysden
cd .xcrysden
cp /usr/share/xcrysden/Tcl/custom-definitions .
and edit the file by uncommenting the "#set toglOpt(accum)  false"
line.
